# restart syslog in cloudlinux

Tags: linux, centos, cloud, centos6

I've recently modified the /var/log/secure log to test a remote log aggregation tool and that, of course, prevented syslog from further writing to that log.

**Question**: How do i restart `syslog` on this `CloudLinux` box I have?

I'm used to syslog being under `/etc/init.d/syslog` for other Linux distros and just a simple restart command does it however on `CloudLinux` syslog is under `/etc/logrotate/syslog` and, as far as I could read, it's part of a cron job now or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On CloudLinux 6 (as well as CentOS6) it is /etc/init.d/rsyslog